# Sequelize.js. How to join 2 tables (one to one)

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables

```
--- registries
id name
1  dev
--- registries_meta
registryId data
1          {dev: true}
```

And how to join it?
My code:

```
  public static associate() {
    RegistriesModel.hasOne(RegistriesMetaModel, { foreignKey: 'registryId', sourceKey: 'id' });
    RegistriesModel.belongsTo(RegistriesMetaModel, { foreignKey: 'id' });
    return;
  }
```

I got an error:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: RegistriesMetaModel.id
```

How to fix thia stupid associations?
Expected query:

```
SELECT * FROM registries LEFT JOIN registries_meta ON registries.id = registries_meta.registryId;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `Registries` model is target model, and it has `RegistriesMeta`. So when defining association you need to define them like below:

```js
   Registries.hasOne(RegistriesMeta, {
       foreignKey: "registryId"
   });
   RegistriesMeta.belongsTo(Registries, {
       foreignKey: "registryId"
   });
```

Comment: No =( I got a same problem
```